# How to quit/halt/terminate/kill/stop a MSBuild process?

Tags: msbuild

I know 
`<Error... />`
task can stop the running process but it will raise an error. How can I get rid of that error but still be able to quit the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`<Error Code="0" />`